# Class Zend Not Found in Magento 2 – Fix All Zend Errors

Tags: php, magento2.4.6, php8.1

Class Zend not found in magento now. So for that, we have fixes for those classes which is currently using the same but we want to upgrade in latest magento 2.4.X versions.

**common errors of Zend:**

> Error: Class Zend_Json not found
>
> Error: Class Zend_Http_Client not found
>
> Error: Class Zend_Filter not found
>
> Error: Class Zend_Validate not found

How do I solve the above error?

Answer (score 1):

**Method to Solve ‘Error Class Zend not found’ in Magento 2**
**Follow these steps:**

**Step 1: Install Laminas**

1. Magento root directory open terminal
2. run command : **composer require laminas/laminas-serializer** [required: composer install]

**Step 2: Replace Zend Classes with Laminas**

1. Open the .phtml file where you are facing the main.CRITICAL: Error: Class Zend not found in Magento 2.
2. Find and replace the respective Zend classes with that of Laminas as provided in the table below:

[image]

**kudos @Pramod**